# Como enviar string de JavaScript a php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

No logro enviar un `string` desde `Ajax` a `PHP`, este es mi código.

**//JavaScript**

```
function start(){
  var move ="start";
  $.ajax({
    url:'index.php',
    type:'post',
    dataType:'text',
    data:'move'
  })
}
```

**//php**

```
<?php
  $code= $_POST['move'];
  var_dump($code); 
  switch ($code) {
        case 'start':
        echo "from start";
        break;
    case 'right':
        echo "from right";
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
?>
```

En la consola del navegador en response me da esta linea, por lo que entiendo, llega la consulta a `PHP` pero no hay `string`, para comparar en el `switch`.

`string(0) ""`

todo empieza con un:

```
<button id="start" onclick="start();">inicio</button>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

```
function start(){
$.ajax({
    url:'index.php',
    type:'post',
    // lo envías como un objeto en formato JSON
    data:{ move: 'start' }
    // Si quisieras enviar más información 
    data: {move: 'start', otraOpcion: 'miopcion'}
})
}

<?php
// Recibís el valor como lo enviaste
$code= $_POST['move'];
//$otraOpcion= $_POST['otraOpcion'];
var_dump($code); 
switch ($code) {
        case 'start':
        echo "from start";
        break;
    case 'right':
        echo "from right";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}?>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos,

Comment: Al menos explícale por qué tu código funciona, @LudOsorio